# Looping a dataframe with datetime.date in the index Python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, for-loop

I need to loop the following data keeping the first row and subtracting second value with the first (then second with third and so on) for each column:

| Index of rows | 0 | 1 | ... | 959 | 960 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| datetime.date(2021, 3, 1) | -216.097205 | -216.097205 | ... | -198.699325 | -198.699325 |
| datetime.date(2021, 3, 2) | 76.512615 | 76.512615 | ... | -198.699325 | -198.699325 |
| datetime.date(2021, 3, 3) | -645.633370 | -645.633370 | ... | 637.719615 | 637.719615 |

To have this:

| Index of rows | 0 (first column) | 1 | ... | 959 | 960 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| datetime.date(2021, 3, 1) | -216.097205 | -216.097205 | ... | -198.699325 | -198.699325 |
| datetime.date(2021, 3, 2) | 292.6098 | 292.6098 | ... | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2021, 3, 3) | -722.14 | -722.14 | ... | 836.4189 | 836.4189 |

Basically I need to convert the cumulative profit of the first df into a dataframe of single day PNL.

Have tried with this code:

```
def cumdiff_RowDatetime(df,axis):
if axis==1 :
    for x, y in enumerate(df.columns):
        if x == 0:
            cf[y] = df[y]
        else:
            cf[y] = df[y] - df[df.columns[x - 1]]
    return cf
else :
    for x in enumerate(df.columns):
        for y in df.iterrows():
            if x == 0:
                cf[y] = df[y]
            else:
                cf[y] = df[y] - df[df.columns[x - 1]]
    return cf

AAATB=cumdiff_RowDatetime(AAAT,axis=0)
```

But I get the following error. "KeyError: (datetime.date(2021, 3, 1), 0     -216.097205"
Guess my function is completely wrong or it has a problem with the datetime.date in the rows index.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
df = df.diff().fillna(df)
```

Result:

|  | 0 | 1 | 959 | 960 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| datetime.date(2021, 3, 1) | -216.097 | -216.097 | -198.699 | -198.699 |
| datetime.date(2021, 3, 2) | 292.61 | 292.61 | 0 | 0 |
| datetime.date(2021, 3, 3) | -722.146 | -722.146 | 836.419 | 836.419 |

Comment: Thanks. I'll earn those 15 points just to vote your answer! ;)